# Newly added keyword fields in Elascticsearch index is not searchable

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

ES version: 6.8.x

Hi,

I added 2 new `keyword` fields to some of my documents (10%) in an index. But those 2 new fields are not searchable. I refreshed the field list from `kibana` (management -> index pattern -> Refresh button). And in `kibana` I have green dots in the `Searchable` and `Aggregatable` columns for those 2 fields. But whey I try to search them from `kibana`, or from the dev tool (directly in ES) I see no result.

The documents in my index previously had 5 `keyword` fields, and I added 2 new `keyword` fields.
The mapping for those 2 fields is `keyword`. I double-checked it.

What could be the problem? How can I solve it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

Delete and re-create the index pattern in Kibana. It will work.

Comment: It does not work. Also, it broke all the existing visualization. Please take care before suggesting something that may cause more harm than good.